# Exporting Null integer data from SQL Server 2005 to a file

Tags: sql-server-2005

When I export records using a query from the SQL Server 2005 import export wizard to a comma delimited file, the integer data type column with a `NULL` value is exported as `,,` i.e. the null is replaced by no character, while I want the output to be `,NULL,`.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) tool. It can export query results. Use the native format and use the same bcp tool to import the data at destination.

Among other advantages (speed, minimal logging, correct code page and unicode handling, batching etc etc) you will also get correct NULL handling in the process. bcp allows fine tune control over NULLs, see [Keep Nulls or Use Default Values During Bulk Import (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187887.aspx).

If you insist on csv files then there is fundamental no way of representing NULLs, see [BCP and NULL Values](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/98620):

> The only non-ambiguous way to represent NULL in character-mode BCP is by using two adjacent delimiters in a character-delimited file. Manipulation of the source file to achieve this state is possible via several techniques. Alternatively, if 0 or spaces in the destination SQL column has no valid meaning for the particular database, you can change it to NULL via a bulk UPDATE statement following the BCP in.

Answer (score 0):

Null means no value, but you want a string value of 'NULL' to be exported. Perhaps you should use a CASE statement in your query to substitute a string for nulls:

```
case 
    when yourColumn is null then 'NULL' 
    else cast(yourColumn as varchar(100)) 
end as IntegerColumn
```

Comment: Other options would be to use `ISNULL()` function or `COALESCE()` function.

Comment: if select cola,colb,colc from table_1 order by cold is my query, how do I use isNull function to serve the purpose ?

Comment: Not sure ISNULL or COALESCE would work as you need to return a consistent data type, which in this case would need to be a varchar/nvarchar.